# How get List of items from Netsuite using java api

Tags: netsuite, suitetalk

How I can get Item list from NetSuite using suite talk java API. I am
 able to get single item using internal Id but I need to get All list of items or by pagination (batch). Please advise how can I do this?

Code for get one inventory item:

```
    RecordRef recordRefs=new RecordRef();
    recordRefs.setType(RecordType.inventoryItem);
    recordRefs.setInternalId("6")
    ReadResponseList responseList = client.callGetRecords(recordRefs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a search. You'll probably want an advanced search, since you're retrieving so many results. Here's a great example of an advanced search with pagination: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47538464/10393810

(Note that you will be using an `ItemSearchAdvanced`, not `TransactionSearchAdvanced` as in the example)